# Firing onchange event when Ember.Select option is changed

Tags: ember.js

I have been trying to bind an event to select element generated via `Ember.Select` but I am having no luck. I have bunch of selects in my page and I wanted to populate the options of a select based on the value of another. I created a select view like :

```
AS.ClientSelectView = Ember.Select.extend({
    contentBinding:"AS.customerController",
    selectionBinding:"AS.SelectedClient.client",
    optionLabelPath : "content.name",
    optionValuePath : "content.id",
    change: function () {
          console.log(AS.SelectedClient.client.get('name'));
    }
});
```

but when the change event fires, it does not show the currently selected element's value but it shows the prior selected options value.

Here is the jsbin link : http://jsbin.com/iSiCUmU/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create an object of type AS.SelectedClient and then use that object in you select:

```
AS.selectedClient = AS.SelectedClient.create();

AS.ClientSelectView = Ember.Select.extend({
  contentBinding: "AS.customerController",
  selectionBinding: "AS.selectedClient.client",
  optionLabelPath : "content.name",
  optionValuePath : "content.id"
});
```